# Why is cups sometimes unable to read its TLS key and certificate depending on location of symlink?

Tags: 18.04, permissions, printing, ssl

I have cups failing to establish a connection over https://.

```
→ curl https://possum.int.gg3.net:631/adsf -I
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to possum.int.gg3.net:631
```

An strace on the process shows that it fails to open the key:

```
[pid 12399] access("/etc/cups/ssl/possum.int.gg3.net.crt", R_OK) = 0
[pid 12399] access("/etc/cups/ssl/possum.int.gg3.net.key", R_OK) = 0
[pid 12399] access("/etc/cups/ssl/possum.int.gg3.net.crt", R_OK) = 0
[pid 12399] access("/etc/cups/ssl/possum.int.gg3.net.key", R_OK) = 0
[pid 12399] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/cups/ssl/possum.int.gg3.net.key", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

This is with my `/etc/cups/ssl` directory looking like this:

```
root@possum:/etc/cups/ssl# find /possum.int.gg3.net.* ./ -exec ls -dgG {} + ; 
drwx------ 1   88 Oct  1 19:52 ./
lrwxrwxrwx 1   23 Oct  1 19:52 ./possum.int.gg3.net.crt -> /possum.int.gg3.net.crt
lrwxrwxrwx 1   23 Oct  1 19:52 ./possum.int.gg3.net.key -> /possum.int.gg3.net.key
-rw------- 1 3810 Oct  1 18:58 /possum.int.gg3.net.crt
-rw------- 1 1708 Oct  1 18:58 /possum.int.gg3.net.key
```

However, if I move the files to `/tmp` or to `/opt`, it starts working.

```
root@possum:/etc/cups/ssl# mv -vi /possum.int.gg3.net.* /opt/
renamed '/possum.int.gg3.net.crt' -> '/opt/possum.int.gg3.net.crt'
renamed '/possum.int.gg3.net.key' -> '/opt/possum.int.gg3.net.key'

root@possum:/etc/cups/ssl# ln -svf -t . /opt/possum.int.gg3.net.*
'./possum.int.gg3.net.crt' -> '/opt/possum.int.gg3.net.crt'
'./possum.int.gg3.net.key' -> '/opt/possum.int.gg3.net.key'
```

Tried a few other directories, but cannot figure out the pattern. E.g., it works if the links point to `/tmp`, `/opt`, or `./file/`, but does not work if they point to `/usr`, `/`, or `/etc/letsencrypt/live/possum.int.gg3.net` (the last one is what I really need to do).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was a problem with the apparmor profile of cups, which was not allowing the process to read files in the /etc/letsencrypt directory.

I recently installed livepatch which installed snapd which installed **and enabled** apparmor.

The solution is to allow these in the profile. E.g.

```
$ sudo tee -a /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.cupsd <<EOF
>   /etc/letsencrypt/live/** r,
>   /etc/letsencrypt/archive/** r,
> EOF
$ sudo systemctl restart apparmor
```